# Wordpress plugin development - AJAX JSON data is sending correctly but PHP response is always 0, why?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, wordpress

I must be missing something simple here. Firebug shows data being sent exactly as it should in NET tab (NET tab-> Post -> Parameters). PHP function will not even echo simple text.

The PHP:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_process_json', 'process_json_received');
add_action('wp_ajax_process_json', 'process_json_received');

function process_json_received(){
echo "ANYTHING...";
exit;
}
```

The JS/Jquery (sending correctly)

```
var data =  JSON.stringify({ action: 'process_json', value_name: 'value'  });//generic sample

$.ajax({ url: 'http://localhost:12345/site_name/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', 
               data: {data: data},
               type: 'post',
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function (response) {
               alert("Got this from the server: " + response);
               console.log( response );
               $('body').append(response); // <-- Append the ajax response to the page body
            },
            complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, text_status) {

                  },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert("Error getting php file");
            }
});
```

Again, it doesn't matter what is in the PHP function, the response is always 0. It could be an "enqueue_scripts" thing but ajax request is sending exactly as it should. NET tab in Firebug shows perfect json data so the problem has to be with the PHP function (or correct access to it). Maybe Wordpress is somehow blocking it??? Has to be something simple - I'm hoping a fresh set of eyes will help. Thanks in advance...

Comment: are you getting alert in Error function or "Success' Console.log to show zero?. If you are getting into Success then error is in PHP for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it using the following code:

In main PHP plugin file:

```
echo "<script src='URL PATH TO/ajax_file.js' type='text/javascript'></script>";

add_action( 'wp_ajax_foobar', 'foobar_handler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_foobar', 'foobar_handler' );
function foobar_handler() {
    // Handle request then generate response
    echo "ANYTHING..."; // do stuff here
    die(); // avoids extra 0 at the end of the response
}
```

In ajax_file.js: (referred to above in script tag)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

   $('#id_to_submit_button').click( function() {
      var data = {
         action : 'foobar',
         Whatever : '1234',
      }
      ;
      // ajaxurl only needed for front - facing public pages, comment out for back end pages
      var ajaxurl = 'http://SITE_URL/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
      jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
         alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
      }
      );
   }
   );
}
);
```

As soon as I included the script in this way it worked, it would not when placed in a PHP function as many sources suggest. I tried soooo many other ways that should have worked. I went step by step on the Wordpress codex pages (many times) and several other tutorials. Enqueueing scripts, registering scripts, following all recommended practices. I still don't understand why this way works for me and all the other "correct" ways didn't. Could be something in my local server environment. Big thanks to those who answered and tried to help. God knows I have gotten the quick answer on StackOverflow enough times, I hope this saves someone the long hours I spent testing and troubleshooting...

Answer (score 1):

Because `ANYTHING...` isn't correct json format. Try `echo json_encode(array('msg' => 'test'));` This causes that JQuery have a parsing error (not error from receive)

Comment: The anything part I just put here it is not actually in the code. Just there as an example that nothing will echo. Tried your method, doesn't work. Response is still 0 - Thanks anyway

Comment: he is not getting javascript parse error, but response as 0, which is wordpress's default when it doesn't get correct input for ajax call.

Comment: Firebug is showing data sent correctly via NET -> Post -> Parameters, so I do not think the problem is in the AJAX call. More likely the PHP or something missing that is expected by Wordpress.

Comment: did you try my solution? Check Wordpress documentation for more.

Comment: @Sumit Gupta - Would Firebug show correct data being sent in JSON format (NET tab-> Post -> Parameters) if ajax call had issues? I did not think so but I could be wrong. It is entirely possible that I am troubleshooting the wrong thing. What other things might Wordpress be expecting for front end AJAX call that I have not included? This issue has me at a dead stop in development, database saves via AJAX are absolutely necessary for this project. -Thanks for your input

Comment: what firebug shows is correct, it is just the prespective of what you see, you are seeing a string, but as wordpress documentation says they expect Javascript object not javascript string. And yes, I make wordpress plugin so just try the change.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line in javascript from

```
var data =  JSON.stringify({ action: 'process_json', value_name: 'value'  });//generic sample
```

to

```
var data =  { action: 'process_json', value_name: 'value'  };
```

Wordpress expect POST Data so it can read $_POST['action], you should never Stringify it, but use core javascript object only.

Read more about it : http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29

EDIT:

Also change `data: {data: data},` to `data: data,`

:) I miss that last time.

Comment: When I do not stringify Firebug shows data like this insted of (name: value) pairs: data[action] process_json
data[value_name] value                                            still returns 0

Comment: Also change "data: {data: data}," to " data: data, "

Comment: when I change that I get error response "Error getting php file". This produces problem with the AJAX call not the php side of things. :(

Comment: not sure exactly what you mean. No matter what is in PHP function it returns 0. Whether echo or return is used. Basically it is finding the PHP function but for some reason not executing it

Comment: Well use fiddler or see the next answer here, what I mean.

Comment: In the working version I posted below I did not stringify, even though it did not fix the above code by eliminating it. This was a correct suggestion. Thanks @Sumit Gupta for pointing this out